# How to get the first charecters from array of strings in case insensitive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In my iPhone app i have an array of stings.

fron that string i need to get the array of first charecters. For this i have implemented logic as follow. it works but in this i have retrieve charectes twicw 1.Small letters and 2.Capital letters.

I need to get only capital letters even it is the small letter.

like Only **"A"** for **America, Africa and america, antantica**

```
contactIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      for (int i=0; i<[contactsArray count]-1; i++){
            //---get the first char of each state---
            char alphabet = [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
            NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];

            //---add each letter to the index array---
            if (![contactIndex containsObject:uniChar])
            {            
                  [contactIndex addObject:uniChar];
            }        
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Example, This will work

```
NSMutableArray *contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"America",@"Africa",@"america",@"antantica", nil];    

for (int i=0; i<[contactsArray count]; i++){

        NSString *alphabet = [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] uppercaseString];

        NSString *firstCharactor = [alphabet substringToIndex:1];

       [contactIndex addObject:firstCharactor];

        NSLog(@"%@",firstCharactor);

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the good old fashion C function: `toupper(str)`

Or you can use the `uppercaseString()` method:

```
NSString* changeString = [upperString uppercaseString];
```